# What should I do about two stray dogs I see in my neighbourhood?

Tags: dogs

I just saw two dogs with no collar or any form of identification. I called one up to me and lost track of the other. They appear young and I think they might be pit-bulls. They seem friendly as I could pet the one who came up to me with no problem, but there are other dogs all over the neighborhood that they go and bark at which takes their attention off me and means I can't get it to follow me. I don't want to grab or pull on it because I'm not sure if it will bite and I have no collar or leash with me. 
What can I do?

Comment: what part of the world are you in, the risks are different in the US vs India, for example

Comment: I live in the U.S.

Comment: Are you sure they are strays? I recall some dogs have identification tattooed inside the ear. Or they may have an identifying chip on them.

Comment: Are there animal protection services in your area? If they are strays, those would be the ones to approach. I am not sure if this is true for the US as well, but at least in Germany, the Police would at least be able to refer you to the proper people to approach....

Comment: I actually got one back to its owner. The other I could not find as it had ran off.

Answer (score 3):

I don't advise "catching" the dogs yourself. Stray or lost dogs are often anxious and scared, and a leash or stranger holding them back may only increase their anxiety. I suggest calling your local rescue organization first. They know best how to approach animals and can scan take the dogs to a vet to scan for a microchip. Many also have no kill policies and wonderful foster homes on hand for those dogs without a home. If you are unable to locate local rescue organizations, I suggest contacting animal control. Often dog owners go to animal control when looking for lost pets. The experience there can be mixed depending on your location, which is why I suggest rescue orgs first. Good luck!